# When trying to shade smooth the model, it makes this gap between the faces. Why does it do that, and how can I fix it?

Tags: smooth

I'm still relativly new to blender and I've been working on a model. I'm trying to clean up the topology and smoothe the model, but when trying to apply "shade smooth" (while subdivision modiffier is on in both cases) these gaps appear between the faces. Why does it happen and how can i fix it?

[image: Shaded smooth]
[image: Shaded flat]
[image: Shadded smooth and you can see the mesh]

Comment: Hello, overlapping vertices, inside faces, flipped faces? Maybe share your file...

Comment: I've managed to fix it, the problem was flipped faces!

Comment: Doubled edges perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have flipped faces, select all in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>